# Deletion of specific node from singly Linked list with the help of data given

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to delete the node of specific data. For this, I am using deleteNode function but not able to delete. Please see the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
    public:
    int data;
    node* next;

    ///constructor for initializing the data-

    node(int d)
    {
        data=d;
        next=NULL;
    }

};
void addAtEnd(node* &head,int data)
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=new node(data);
        return ;
    }
  node* temp=head;
  while(temp->next!=NULL)
  {
      temp=temp->next;
  }
  node* n =new node(data);
  n->data=data;
  temp->next=n;
  n->next=NULL;
  return;
}
AddAtTail(node* head,int d)
{
  node* ptr=head;
  while(ptr->next!=NULL)
  {
      ptr=ptr->next;
  }
  node *n=new node(d);
  ptr->next=n;
  n->next=NULL;


}
AddAtPosition(node* head,int p,int d)
{

    ///2 3 4 6 7 8 -1
    ///4th Position-
    node*ptr=head;
    int jump=1;
    while(jump<=p-1)
    {
        jump++;
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    node*n=new node(d);
    n->next=ptr->next;
    ptr->next=n;


}

/// Delete First node
void deleteFirst(node *&head)
{
    head=head->next;

}

///Delete last node;
void deleteLast(node* head)
{
  node* ptr=head;
  while(ptr->next->next!=NULL)
  {
      ptr=ptr->next;
  }
  ptr->next=NULL;
}
**///Delete Specific Node  :-**
```

Here the function starts for deleting the node. I am trying to delete the node that has data 3 I am taking data as input from main function.

```
void deleteData(node* head,int d)
{
    node*ptr=head;
    while(ptr->next!=NULL)
    {
       if(ptr->next->data==d)
       {
         ptr=ptr->next->next;
         return;
       }
       ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}


void takeInput(node*& head)
{

    int d;
    cin>>d;
    while(d!=-1)
    {
      addAtEnd(head,d);
      cin>>d;

    }
}
void print(node* head)
{
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<head->data<<"=>";
        head=head->next;
    }
}
AddAtFront(node* &head,int d)
{
   ///create new node;
   node*n=new node(d);
   n->next=head;
   head=n;


}

int main()
{
    node* head(NULL);
    takeInput(head);
    print(head);
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<"---------- Here The Insertion Process starts at different Positions -----------"<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Adding at Tail"<<endl;

    AddAtTail(head,9);
    print(head);
    cout<<endl<<"Adding at Position p"<<endl;
    int p,d;

    cout<<"Enter Position and data :"<<endl;
    cin>>p>>d;
    AddAtPosition(head,p,d);
    print(head);
    cout<<endl<<"Adding at Front"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter data to add at front : "<<endl;
    cin>>d;
    AddAtFront(head,d);

    print(head);
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"--------------------  NOW LETS PERFORM DELETION  ------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Deleting first node :"<<endl;
    deleteFirst(head);
    print(head);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Deleting Last node :"<<endl;
    deleteLast(head);
    print(head);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"deleting specific node"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter data to delete"<<endl;
    cin>>d;
    deleteData(head,d);
    print(head);
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Please see DeleteNode function in which I am trying to delete the node.
Why node is not deleting? Here is the function:

```
**///Delete Specific Node i.e- data :-**
    void deleteData(node* head,int d)
    {
        node*ptr=head;
        while(ptr->next!=NULL)
        {
           if(ptr->next->data==d)
           {
             ptr=ptr->next->next;
             return;
           }
           ptr=ptr->next;
        }
    }
```

But Node is not deleting.

Comment: Off topic-ish: That which you `new` you should also `delete`.

Comment: Recommend fixing the functions missing their return types.

Comment: Program hangs because of a cycle in the list before I can duplicate your problem. You have multiple bugs.

Comment: Using the mark-1 eyeball, `ptr=ptr->next->next;` modifies a temporary local and makes no change to the list.

Comment: `deleteData` : 1) Never checks for `head` being NULL 2) Never checks the data held by `head` 3) `ptr=ptr->next->next;` is wrong. Maybe `ptr->next=ptr->next->next;` 4) Never calls `delete`

Comment: `addAtEnd`: The lines `n->data=data;` and `n->next=NULL;` can be deleted as  the constructor have done that already

Answer (score 1):

Your `delete...` functions are not actually deleting anything. You are just manipulating pointers but are leaking the actual `node` objects. And you are not taking into account the possibility that the node being deleted is the `head` node, which requires updating the `head` to point at the next node.

Also, your functions will crash on an empty list, and `deleteLast` will crash on a list with fewer than 2 nodes.

And `deleteData` is not enumerating nodes correctly.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node {
public:
    int data;
    node* next;

    ///constructor for initializing the data-

    node(int d) {
        data=d;
        next=NULL;
    }
};

node* findLast(node *head, node **before) {
    if (before) *before = NULL;
    node *last = head;
    if (last) {
        while (last->next) {
            if (before) *before = last;
            last = last->next;
        }
    }
    return last;
}

node* addAtFront(node* &head, int data) {
    node* n = new node(data);
    n->next = head;
    head = n;
    return n;
}

node* addAtEnd(node* &head, int data) {
    node *last = findLast(head, NULL);
    node* n = new node(data);
    if (last) {
        last->next = n;
    } else {
        head = n;
    }
    return n;
}

node* addAtPosition(node* &head, int p, int d) {
    if ((!head) || (p <= 0)) {
        return addAtFront(head, d);
    }
    node *ptr = head;
    node *temp;
    do {
        temp = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    while ((ptr) && (--p > 0));
    node *n = new node(d);
    n->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = n;
    return n;
}

/// Delete First node
void deleteFirst(node* &head) {
    if (head) {
        node *ptr = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete ptr;
    }
}

///Delete last node
void deleteLast(node* &head) {
    node *beforeLast;
    node *last = findLast(head, &beforeLast);
    if (last) {
        if (beforeLast) {
            beforeLast->next = NULL;
        }
        if (head == last) {
            head = NULL;
        }
        delete last;
    }
}

///Delete Specific Node
void deleteData(node* &head, int d) {
    node *before = NULL;
    node *ptr = head;
    while (ptr) {
        if (ptr->data == d) {
            if (before) {
                before->next = ptr->next;
            }
            if (head == ptr) {
                head = head->next;
            }
            delete ptr;
            return;
        }
        before = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

void takeInput(node* &head) {
    int d;
    if (!((cin >> d) && (d != -1))) return;
    node *last = findLast(head, NULL);
    node *n = new node(d);
    if (last) {
        last->next = n;
    } else {
        head = n;
    }
    last = n;
    while ((cin >> d) && (d != -1)) {
        n = new node(d);
        last->next = n;
        last = n;
    }
}

void print(node* head) {
    while (head) {
        cout << head->data << "=>";
        head = head->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    node* head = NULL;

    takeInput(head);
    print(head);
    cout << endl;

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout <<     "---------- Here The Insertion Process starts at different Positions -----------" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Adding at End" << endl;
    addToEnd(head, 9);
    print(head);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Adding at Position p" << endl;
    int p, d;
    cout << "Enter Position and data :" << endl;
    if (cin >> p >> d) {
        addAtPosition(head, p, d);
        print(head);
        cout << endl;
    } 

    cout << "Adding at Front" << endl;
    cout << "Enter data to add at front : " << endl;
    if (cin >> d) {
        addAtFront(head, d);
        print(head);
        cout << endl;
    } 

    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    cout << "-------------------- NOW LETS PERFORM DELETION ------------------" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Deleting first node :" << endl;
    deleteFirst(head);
    print(head);
    cout << endl;

    cout << endl << "Deleting Last node :" << endl;
    deleteLast(head);
    print(head);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "deleting specific node" << endl;
    cout << "Enter data to delete" << endl;
    if (cin >> d) {
        deleteData(head, d);
        print(head);
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "deleting remaining nodes" << endl;
    node *ptr = head;
    while (ptr) {
        node *temp = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
        delete temp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, you really should be using [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) (double linked) or [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) (single linked) instead.  Let the STL do the hard work for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your delete node function, you are changing the value of the local variable, ptr.  But you are not changing the "next" pointer of the node pointing to the one you want to delete.  So it stays in the list.  The value of your local pointer becomes irrelevant as soon as you leave the function.
   This line is the problem: `ptr=ptr->next->next;`

You need to change its "next" value.  Something like (I haven't compiled and tested this; it is a suggestion to point you in the right direction.)

```
void deleteData(node* head,int d)
{
    node*ptr=head;

    while(ptr->next!=NULL)
    {
       if(ptr->next->data==d)
       { /* pointer->next points to the node you want to delete.  
            point it instead to the one beyond */
         ptr->next=ptr->next->next;
         return;
       }

       ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}
```

2. You will then have a memory leak, as you are not freeing the memory to the node you are deleting.

You'd need something like:

```
void deleteData(node* head,int d)
{
    node*ptr=head;

    while(ptr->next!=NULL)
    {
        if(ptr->next->data==d)
        { /* pointer->next points to the node you want to delete.  
             point it instead to the one beyond, 
             freeing the memory of the deleted node */
             node * pNodeToDelete = ptr->next;                      
             ptr->next=ptr->next->next;
             free(pNodeToDelete)
             return;
        }

        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: If someone knows how to get my last brace inside the code block, please edit it or, better yet, tell me how.  Yes, I selected it with the rest of the code block when I pressed the {} button.  I tried also deleting it and reinserting it when already in the code block......thanks!

Comment: ptr->next=ptr->next->next; . But when I store it in a pointer then program is not giving correct output. So I didn't free the memory

Comment: I don't understand your last comment -- what do you mean by, "But when I store it in a pointer then program is not giving correct output."?  What output are you expecting that it is not giving?  What do you mean by "when I store it in a pointer"?

Comment: @kindacoder -- is it working for you now?  I didn't understand your last question, in the comment above my last one.